# How to addAttributeToFilter?

Tags: search, magento

I am trying to get Collection of all available products in Magento & Filter that collection

Here is my code:

```
$searcher = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$searcher->addAttributeToSelect('name');
echo count($searcher);
$searcher->addAttributeToFilter('name',array('like' => 'paper'));
$searcher->load();
echo count($searcher);
```

Now first time it gives count 745(FOR ALL PRODUCTS) but after filtering it still shows 745.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: This works for me:**

```
$searcher = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('name',array('eq' => 'paper'));
$searcher->load();
echo count($searcher);
```

Comment: Ok Kenny I am trying this & giving you answer. Thanks very much for your fast reply.

Comment: Please see this link "http://eagle.arvixe.com/~houselav/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?name=paper&description=&short_description=&sku=&price[from]=&price[to]=".

Comment: Under All Tags there is 745745. first 745 is before filter & then after filter.

Comment: Ya still problem remains same. Any Help More Please?

Comment: ok Kenny but can you tell me how can I take Advance Search Result to another file? I am having requirement that To Take Whole Result of Advance Search in sidebar(Left side). I have made a separate file for this & displayed what I desired but the thing is that is only of current page's items but I want whole result.

Comment: I am having requirement to take the categories of each & every product of Advance Search Result to left bar. Categories are loaded but they are of only of current page's produts that is 12. I actually want the whole search result products. So that's why I took the product collection & then decided to filter it but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Ok, I think it's best that you open up a new question for this as it's a completely different thing. Also if the code worked, don't forget to accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks very much Kenny for your all help:).